# a union class with a member (object) that has overloaded equals operator

Tags: c++

Why  cant a union class have a member object that has overloaded equals operator? The restriction is on the  member object of the union class not the object of the union class!

Comment: Do you mean the equality operator (`==`) or the assignment operator (`=`)? And which C++ version, 03 or 11?

Comment: I'm failing to find that prohibition in the standard, and g++ 4.5 seems to compile such an operator. Can you provide the standard reference that prohibits this?

Comment: What makes you think you can't overload the "equals" operator in unions?

Answer (score 3):

> why can't we overload "equals" operator in a union class?

**We can.**

It's not prohibited, and it works just fine. For example:

```
#include <cassert>

union T
{
    int x;
    int y;

    T& operator=(const T& other)
    {
        x = other.x;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const T& other)
    {
        return x == other.x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    T a{5};
    T b{6};

    a = b;
    assert(a == b);
}
```

### [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30bd53442d84e5e1)

---

> Union class in c++ has some restriction compared to the normal class. one of the restriction is the overloading = operator.

This is simply not true.

However, if one of the *members* has a user-defined `operator=`, then the union itself must have one too:

> `[C++11: 9.5/2]:` *[..] [ Note:* **If any non-static data member of a union has a non-trivial** default constructor (12.1), copy constructor (12.8), move constructor (12.8), **copy assignment operator** (12.8), move assignment operator (12.8), or destructor (12.4), **the corresponding member function of the union must be user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted** (8.4.3) for the union. *—end note ] [..]*

Comment: oops! .. it said it cannot have an object as a member that overloads equals operator as a member.

Comment: @user3140137: That's subtly but importantly different from what you said in your question. What prevented you from presenting a [testcase](http://sscce.org)? See the end of my answer.